# Binding value in orderby not working with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

```
SELECT * FROM `student` ORDER BY :sortName :sortDir Limit :limitFrom,:limitCount;
```

Code java:

```
    Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    paramMap.put("sortName", "%" + sortName + "%");
            paramMap.put("sortDir", sortDir);
            paramMap.put("limitFrom", pageIndex * pageSize);
            paramMap.put("limitCount", pageSize);
    List<Student> list = (List<Student>) super.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sqlSearch, paramMap, new StudentMapper());

protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }
```

input is (pageIndex, pageSize, sortName, sortDir) = (2,2,"id", "desc")
real output: 8 9 10 11 (with id)
expectation: 11 10 9 8

Answer (score 3):

Placeholders like `?` and `:param` can only be used for parameter values not for column names, sorting and pagination purposes. For those requirements you should **safely** concatenate strings together.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Do you have another way to use all this param with one method? I don't want to split sql.

Comment: Either split the sql or go for other abstractions such as `Spring Data JPA` which is handling sorting and pagination elegantly

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Comment: I was cracking my head open over this issue, wondering why my query was returning the correct order, by `jdbcTemplate.query()` had completely the wrong order. Thank you so much.